# Can't set Chromium as default browser

Tags: 11.04, chromium, default-browser

I open Chromium and the browser ask me if I want to set it as my default browser. I click on "set as default" and close the browser.

But when I open Chromium again I get the same question. Ubuntu 11.04 seems not to set Chromium correctly as my default browser.

How to fix that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try changing your your preferred browser.

#### 17.10+

Settings > Details > Default Applications

[image: screenshot]

#### On older versions

1. Open **Preferred Applications** from
   *Preferences > Preferred Appplications.*

   [image]
2. Change the default **Web Browser** to
   your liking.

   [image]

Comment: It's definitely worth trying to set it through Preferred Applications. There was (and possibly still is) [a strange bug if you didn't set it this way](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/natty/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/670128).

Comment: That's it! After changing the settings in Preferred Applications and setting Chromium as default browser again everything is working fine. Maybe a problem with a restore of an Ubuntu 10.10 backup.

Comment: I had to wait a minute ;-) Now it's accepted. Thanx. :-)

Answer (score 8):

To change the browser globally, run the next command in a terminal:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser
```

Enter the number of `chromium-browser` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm it.

Comment: That's not working...

Comment: `update-alternatives` should work (note the extra `s`)

Comment: @1passenger: the `s` after `update-alternative` slipped out. Try the new command.

Comment: Sorry, mistake in writing. I meant update-alternatives and not update-alternative.

Comment: Somehow I had two /usr/bin/chromium-browser in the list. One in auto and one in manual mode, but the manual one was selected. After I changed to the auto one it works.

Answer (score 1):

Start google-chrome from a terminal in the foreground (leave off the &):

me:/home/me> `google-chrome`

Click on the prompt to make chrome the default browser.... notice that it is getting a permissions problem on `.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`. The applications directory is owned by `root` and chrome was running as `me`. In order to fix the problem, I used:

```
chown -R me.me .local
```

Then I restarted google-chrome. It created the following entries in

`cat .local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`

```
[Default Applications]
text/html=google-chrome.desktop
text/xml=google-chrome.desktop
x-scheme-handler/http=google-chrome.desktop
x-scheme-handler/https=google-chrome.desktop
x-scheme-handler/about=google-chrome.desktop
x-scheme-handler/unknown=google-chrome.desktop
```

I suppose you could just create those entries in the file if there is a security problem with changing the owner of the `.local` directory.

Comment: It's actually the opposite of "a security problem with changing the owner of the .local directory". The only way the `.local ` directory will have `root` ownership is if you executed a program with `sudo root` before the `.local ` directory was created, and then it becomes very important to fix the ownership.

Answer (score 0):

For me updating the alternatives in Ubuntu 19.10 did not work, it appears it depends on the fact URLs are opened by xdg-open, and I found that this made it work:

```
xdg-settings set default-web-browser chromium-browser.desktop
```